# HTML5 / CSS: How do you create pixelated text (upscale with sharp edges)

Tags: javascript, html, css, text, game-engine

I'm making simple games in HTML5 some of which use sprite graphics. Upscaling images is easy: You draw your sprite at its minimum resolution, scale the element to your desired `width` and `height`, add the CSS flags `image-rendering: pixelated; image-rendering: crisp-edges;` to retain sharp edges.

But what about text, how do you pixelate it for consistency, can the text in `innerHTML` also be upscaled and sharpened? My text appears smooth and at high resolution which breaks the styling. Just as there's `image-rendering` for graphics there seems to be a `text-rendering` CSS property, but I'm not seeing how it can be used to achieve the effect.

Comment: Use a pixelated font

Comment: Use canvas text methods instead, that way the text ends up as canvas pixels and behaves exactly like the rest of the canvas. edit: wait, you aren't using a <canvas>, are you? That makes things more complicated.

Comment: Yes: I use simple methods where possible so I often have text as just the `innerHTML` of a `div` element. I'm presuming there's no way to render text stored this way at a small resolution then scale up the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use fonts from websites. I would recommend you google fonts or for this specific case:

https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/style/Pixel

The results should look something like this in CSS:

```
@font-face { 
font-family: myFirstFont; src: url("URL");
}
div {
font-family: myFirstFont;
}
```

Comment: Seems using a custom font is the best option available. Thanks.